# How do I check if a string contains of at least one Chinese character?

Tags: php, string, cjk

How do I check if a string contains of at least one Chinese character?

Comment: What if the string contains one Japanese character?

Comment: What if the string contains one Hindi char?

Comment: These guys are right.  The Chinese set of characters is also contained in other languages.  Japanese is a great example.  Perhaps you need to be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well my point was if any Chinese char is the target in and of itself, that's good enough if the goal is to find it.  Parse rules and business logic are a different subject altogether.  The question was just how do you find any Chinese char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
mb_detect_encoding($str, "big5,gb2312");
```

potentially you need to use [mb_detect_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-order.php) to make it more precise

Comment: it works, but we got to encode the PHP file to UTF-8 without BOM. Thanks a lot ajreal. :)